# Change python variable permanently without using file

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I am currently writing a program in Python that allows my colleague that is a lab technician to store the lent and return record of certain devices. I want to setup only 1 account in the system, and I don't want to save the login details in a text file because students might interfere with it and retrieve sensitive information, and I will compile the python program with py2exe and so if I set the program to rewrite the py file then it won't work. Are there any methods that permanently change a variable after first run?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the possibility to run the python script with a command line argument that overwrites the default value of the variable when executed

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thanks, but is there a particular command that does that? If so can you please write it down for me?